# Json Expression stored in one column

Tags: sql, json, parsing, sql-server-2016

I have a `Json` expression stored in one column in the database. I'm looking to separate/parse out the data to display in multiple columns. Some help Please!

Example is below:

```
"{\"TransactionHeader\":
    {\"BinNumber\":\"000000\",
     \"Version\":\"D0\",
     \"TransactionCode\":\"B1\",
     \"ProcessorControl\":\"PBMICCCE\",
     \"TransactionCount\":\"01\",
     \"ServiceProviderQualifier\":\"07\",
     \"ServiceProviderId\":000000,
     \"DateOfService\":\"2/20/1701\",
     \"VendorId\":\"\"
    },
     \"Insurance\":
 }"
```

Comment: I'm guessing all the `\"` should simply be `"`, right? Still I'm not sure it's a valid json because of the value-less properties...

Comment: Sorry that was not the best example. below is a valid Json im trying to parse out. that is just a portion of the whole value. Whats the best way to separate this in sql?

Comment: "TotalAmountPaid":null,"AdditionalMessage":"Max Days = 4;Max Day Supply = 15;Prior Authorization Required;PM excludes;Plan Limitations Exceeded - Max Dollar(2069.15)","AuthorizationNumber":null,"Hint":null,"RejectCodes":"75,76","RejectCount":"02","TransactionResponseStatus":"R"}

Comment: SQL Server 2016 has some built in json support - what you're looking for is probably [`openjson`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If you could [edit] your question to provide a valid json and desired output (would also be good to see what you've already tried) we could probably help you better.